# What does this code do? "data.target == this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, compare

How does this `data.target == this` work?

**jquery example**

```
.mouseup(function(data, handler)
        {
           if(data.target == this)
           {
              // some code
           }
        })
```

Does this compare the objects by comparing each of their respective properties?

I need this check because I want the mouseup only on the parent div and on one child.

```
if (data.target == this || * if this has className XXX  * ) {
   // some code
}
```

Comment: http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/03/18/really-understanding-javascripts-equality-and-identity/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (data.target == this)` evaluates to true if `this` refers to the same object in memory as `data.target`.

The `==` operator does not compare member values. See [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery you don't need to worry about the comparison. Just use `.live` to bind the `mouseup` to the two elements of interest.

```
$(myDiv).live('mouseup',myFunction());
$(myChildElement).live('mouseup',myFunction());
```

You'll need to write code to handle the situation where the mousedown was not on target, e.g. the user clicked down somewhere else and dragged the mouse over your target before releasing.